# Add 0's at the beginning of each integer

Tags: python, numpy, digit

I have lots of files (about 400,000), whose identification is a six-digit number. But if the number is less than 6 digit, then we add 0's at the beginning of the number. For example, if the file identification is 25, the file name is 000025.txt. I wonder how to detect how many digits of a number and how to add the correct number of 0's at beginning of the number. Some of the code is below:

```
import numpy as np
fake_id = np.random.randint(0,400000,400000)
id_change = fake_id[fake_id < 100000]
#### so for fake_id < 100000, we need to find out how many digits of the id, and then we can add the correct number of zeros at the beginning.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could use `log` to figure out how many zeros it has. You could also stringify it and get the length. To add zeros at the start though, it will need to be a string, not a number. Adding 0s to the start of a number is a no-op, unless the language has the octal "feature" that treats numbers with leading zeros as base-8.

Comment: You can't add 0's to the start of an integer, but you can pad the string representation., e.g. `'%010d'%(np.random.randint(0,10000))` or `'{:0>10d}'.format(np.random.randint(0,10000))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `str.format` to "pad" with leading zeros until your number is 6 digits long

```
>>> '{:06d}'.format(25)
'000025'
>>> '{:06d}'.format(5432)
'005432'
>>> '{:06d}'.format(400000)
'400000'
```

To combine this with the rest of your task you can also use this technique to build up the file name

```
>>> '{:06d}.txt'.format(5432)
'005432.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.